# Deleting items in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to delete items, based upon a lookup table i iterate through inside my python dictionary, but am not able to delete the values.
This post depends on python 3.8 to work with.

```
inEvent = {
    "event_data": {
        "event_name": "Test",
        "station_id": "Station1",
        "serial_no": "1234",
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "name": "Temperature from Sensor 1",
            "status": "Passed",
            "value": "21.0",
            "limits": [],
            "units": "°C",
        },
        {
            "name": "Power Measurement CH1",
            "status": "Passed",
            "value": "30.9",
            "limits": [],
            "units": "W",
        },

        {
            "name": "Slope Check: Measured Slope CH1",
            "status": "Passed",
            "value": "1234.5678",
            "limits": {"low": "0", "high": None},
            "units": [],
        },
        {
            "name": "Slope Check: Measured Slope CH2",
            "status": "Passed",
            "value": "-1",
            "limits": [],
            "units": [],
        },
    ],
        "plots": [],
}
```

while iterating over my dictionary i replace matching names, but in rare cases i want to delete the complete matching test entry. for e.g.`{"name": "Slope Check: Measured Slope CH1", "status":"Passed","value": "1234.5678","limits": {"low": "0", "high": None},"units": [],}` should be deleted

```
for t in list(inEvent['tests']):
     eventName = t['name']

     for row in self.LookUpTable.itertuples(index=False): # own lookuptable excel file
         if eventName == row[4] and not pd.isnull(row[5]):    
             t['name'] = row[5]
             break
         elif eventName == row[4] and pd.isnull(row[5]):
             print(inEvent)
             inEvent['tests'].pop(t)
             break
```

Comment: `for index, etc in data: if satisfied: del inEvent["tests"][index]` - for example, `del inEvent["tests"][2] # from your example`. What is the condition, though?

Comment: Found a solution as well. In the elif loop add `inEvent['tests'] = [i for i in inEvent['tests'] if i["name"] != row[4]]` instead of the pop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a nested loop for this. You can do this by looping through all of the keys and values in the dictionary and then loop through all of the keys and values in the nested dictionaries. You can then use an if statement to find the key in teh dictionary that you want to delete. Here is a simple outline of code that you can use (if this does not work then I recommend googling exactly what the issue is and looking further into it):

```html
for key, value in dict.items():
  for k, v in k.items():
    if v == something:
      del key[k]
```